# Selecting Objects in List using Python

Tags: python

To get to the point, here is my input.txt file:

```
Variable 1,Variable 2,Variable 3,Variable 4
Test anxiety,Worry,Emotionality,28
ERS,Reppraisal,Suppression,33
Calling,Money,Love, 69
```

Here is my code:

```
class Psych:
    def __init__(self, des1, des2, des3, value):
        self.__des1 = des1
        self.__des2 = des2
        self.__des3 = des3
        self.__value = value

    def getDes1(self):
        return str(self.__des1)
    
    def getDes2(self):
        return str(self.__des2)

    def getDes3(self):
        return str(self.__des3)
    
    def getValue(self):
        return round(float(self.__value),2)

#Import data
filePath='input.txt'
file=open(filePath)
data=file.readlines()
file.close()

#Remove first row
data2 = data[1:]

#Strip /n
data3 = []
for i in data2:
    data3.append(i.strip())

#Pop, Split, Create and Append Psych objects into listOfVariables
listOfVariables=[]
#Variable 1
var1 = data3.pop(0)
var1 = var1.split(",")
var1 = Psych(var1[0],var1[1],var1[2],float(var1[3]))
listOfVariables.append(var1)

#Variable 2
var2 = data3.pop(0)
var2 = var2.split(",")
var2 = Psych(var2[0],var2[1],var2[2],float(var2[3]))
listOfVariables.append(var2)

#Variable 3
var3 = data3.pop(0)
var3 = var3.split(",")
var3 = Psych(var3[0],var3[1],var3[2],float(var3[3]))
listOfVariables.append(var3)

#Printing function
def printVariables(var):
    print(var.getDes1())
    print(var.getDes2())
    print(var.getDes3())
    print(var.getValue())

#Navigation Menu
print("\nVariable 1")
print("--------------")
print("Variable Details:")
printVariables(var1)
print()
usrInput=input("Press 'N' to see the next variable\nPress 'P' to see the previous variable")
```

Essentially, using the Navigation Menu as the default, I am struggling to write a code that prints out

Variable 2
Variable Details:
output from printVariables(var2)

when usrInput=="N" and prints out

Variable 3
Variable Details:
output from printVariables(var3)

when usrInput=="P".

Similarly, when printVariables(var2) is already executed, usrInput=="N" should print out
Variable 3
Variable Details:
output from printVariables(var3)

and usrInput=="P" should print out

Variable 1
Variable Details:
output from printVariables(var1)

Further issue:
While attempting to solve this problem, I tried

```
test = listOfVariables[-2]
test1 = test[0]
print(test1.getDes1())
```

and encountered this error: TypeError: 'Psych' object is not subscriptable

What does this error mean? Sorry I am very new to programming (as can be seen from my codes) so please give a layperson explanation

Thank you in advance

Comment: You might consider switching to the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package - either of those will make this trivial.

Comment: Your `listOfVariables` is a list of Psych objects so `test = listOfVariables[-2]` is a single Psych object and hence `test[0]` is invalid because `test` is not a list-like object. It's a Psych object, which is not subscriptable.

Comment: Did the supplied answer resolve your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that loads the CSV file, prints out the first row of the CSV, then prompts the user for N=Next, P=Previous, or X=Exit. It cycles through the CSV rows.

```
import csv

FILENAME_CSV = 'input.csv'
COLUMNS = ['Variable 1', 'Variable 2', 'Variable 3', 'Variable 4']

def print_variable(variables, index):
    print('Variable:', index + 1)
    for col in COLUMNS:
        print('\t', variables[index][col])

def load_variables(filename):
    with open(filename) as csv_data:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_data)
        return list(csv_reader)

index = 0
choice = ''
variables = load_variables(FILENAME_CSV)

while choice.upper() != 'X':
    print_variable(variables, index)
    choice = input('Press N for Next, P for Previous, X to exit: ')

    if choice.upper() == 'N':
        index = (index + 1) % len(variables)
    elif choice.upper() == 'P':
        index = (index - 1) % len(variables)
```